# How to integrate this filter into my code?

Tags: javascript

I have some list of names that I take from the array using the Fetch method. Now I'm using the method of searchHandler at the click of a button, I enter the input data into the console:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lovelace-z659k
But I need to enter the input "First name", and click on the button, only a line with that name was displayed. But I don't know how to make the filter myself.
I found the solution on the internet, but unfortunately I can't integrate it into my code.Here it is:

```
getFilteredData() {
    if (!this.state.search){
        return this.state.data
    }
    return this.state.data.filter(item=>{
        return item["firstName"].toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
    });
}
```

How to integrate it into my code? And what to write in the render method?

Comment: you should include the code where you want to integrate it in the question

Comment: @NinaScholz what you do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right direction there. The correct code (with comments explaining the changes) should be:

```
searchHandler = search => {
    // This if checks if search is empty. In that case, it reset the data to print the initial list again
    if (search) {
        // This 'arr' variable is a copy of what you do in your Table.js
        const arr = this.state.data.group && this.state.data.group.first ? this.state.data.group.first : this.state.data;
        const filteredArr = arr.filter((item) => {
            // Here you compare with 'search' instead of 'state.search', since you didn't updated the state to include the search term
            return item["firstName"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        })
        // This will update your state, which also updates the table
        this.setState({data: filteredArr})
    } else {
        // As explained, if search was empty, return everything
        this.resetData();
    }
};

// This is a copy of what you have in componentDidMount
async resetData() {
    const response = await fetch("/data/mass.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        data
    });
}
```

---

### Note:

`includes` is not supported by all browsers, as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). If you need a more reliable solution, you could use `indexOf`, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: can you put your proposed code into my sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lovelace-z659k
Because when I inserted into my componentDidMount here is:
```async resetData() {
    const response = await fetch("/data/mass.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        data
    });
}
```
That's shows an error. And I can't remove the componentDidMount as I need it for some purpose

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-browser-cvmr2

Answer (score 0):

Since your fetched data is an array of objects, and you basically want to filter out the objects which match the serach criteria, heres how you can write your search handler:

```
  searchHandler = search => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const filteredData = {
      group: {
        first: Object.values(data.group.first).filter(item => item.firstName.includes(search)),
      }
    }
    this.setState({ data: filteredData });
  };
```

Basically, what its doing is taking the array of objects out of dataand filter out only those objects which have the name you search for. and sets the filtered array of objects in the same structure as your original data object is and there you go!!
Also you don't have to make any changes to the render method now. Since render method is already working with the state which has data in it. and as soon as you make a search state, data will be updated and available in the render.